# Replacement for ThrowIfCancellationRequested() for cancelling 1000 tasks?

Tags: c#, performance, exception, task, cancellation-token

There are controversial opinions about the performance hit of exceptions.

However, it seems to be a standard way to use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` for cancelling tasks.

Now, if I want to cancel 1000 tasks at once, is `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` still the appropriate way?

** Edit **

Ok, I ran tests and it is a performance problem to use ThrowIfCancellationRequested. 1000 tasks itself are not the problem since the TaskScheduler is clever.

I am still wondering if there is good replacement that does not have the performance disadvantage of ThrowIfCancellationRequested but still has the advantage of Exceptions (easy handling despite of several code hierarchy levels)?

Comment: You might want to run a test to try. And 1000 tasks is massive, that alone might cause you performance issues.

Comment: Ok, I ran tests and it _is_ a performance problem to use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. 1000 tasks itself are not the problem since the TaskScheduler is clever. I am still wondering if there is good replacement that does not have the performance disadvantage of `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` but still has the advantage of Exceptions (easy handling despite of several code hierarchy levels)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the throw is the problem, but your 1000 tasks. Since the scheduler can not run all tasks at once, it will have to queue most of them. When they are all sharing one `CancellationToken`, all running tasks will be cancelled. Then the scheduler will run the the queued tasks that will immediately get cancelled. That's inefficient, because you let the scheduler do all the work just to cancel the task.

Do you pass the `CancellationToken` when you run the task? You might want to do that, so he scheduler knows of the cancellation. What I would recommend is to not schedule all the tasks at once. Cut them into chunks and use `Task.ContinueWith`, where you can prevent the tasks from running altogether.

Comment: No, the 1000 tasks are not such a big problem. If I use `if (IsCancellationRequested) return;` it takes 0.15 ms for each task (150 ms for 1000 tasks). However, if I use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`, it takes 11 ms for each task (11000 ms = 11 s for 1000 tasks)

Comment: If you use `ContinueWith` you will still not face those problems, since you'll have to execute `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` much less often.